# How can I trace how cx_Oracle is attempting to connect to the database?

Tags: python, conda, cx-oracle

I have three Python Anaconda environments which have cx_Oracle and Oracle's Instantclient installed.  I'm using `conda` to provide the virtual environments, which appears to be working fine, and I'm using Oracle Wallet to provide the actual credentials to the system.  Note that these environments do not and will never have SQL*Plus installed on them, since they're only meant to be communicating with the database through a higher abstraction (e.g. Python or Java).

The trouble I'm having is coming from two of the three environments.  When performing the following Python script, connections work fine for just one of the three environments.  Note that the identifier is different across environments, but is roughly the same spirit.

```
import cx_Oracle
import os
os.environ['TNS_ADMIN'] = '/data/config/wallets/app'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('/@ENV_CONNECTION')
```

When I do this on the one environment, I get a cursor instance like I expect and everything works fine.  On the other two, I see this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified
```

I have ***quintuple checked*** the service name and the wallet itself.  There is a Java application which is also using this wallet which would fail to connect if the wallet were considered bad, so I'm ruling that out on principle.

The only remaining unknown is how the wallet itself is being referenced.

How can I introspect how cx_Oracle is referring to my TNS_ADMIN location and pulling in the right directory?  I feel like if I can figure that out, I can solve the rest.

What I have for my environment:

- conda 4.4.11
- instantclient 12.2
- cx_Oracle version 6.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The easiest way to check what cx_Oracle is passing to the lower layers (e.g. Oracle Net) may be to extend the Connection class and add your own logging.  The base class is `cx_Oracle.Connection`, see the example https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/Subclassing.py
- You can run strace or similar to see which Oracle configuration files like tnsnames.ora are being opened.
- Oracle Net tracing can be enabled, see [ADR Diagnostic Parameters in sqlnet.ora](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/netrf/parameters-for-the-sqlnet-ora-file.html#GUID-DF8101E6-ECC6-45C1-B82D-30C40D0D85DD). For a simple trace, I typically create a file "~/.sqlnet.ora" with contents such as:

  `TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT = USER
  ADR_BASE=/tmp`

  Then run the app, and dig down through  the created `/tmp/oradiag_*` directory to the `*.trc` files.

Comment: You can also use sqlplus to connect to the database using the connect string you provided to cx_Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Christopher Jones' answer led me to salvation, but the reality is that the problem was far more subtle than this.

I wound up creating the `sqlnet.ora` files in the home directories of two machines - one that did work and one that didn't.  I noticed a striking difference in the log files.

The "good" box had this entry:

```
2018-07-06 09:59:36.726 : nnftrne:Using tnsnames.ora address (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my.oracle.db.host)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = my_sid))) for name ENV_CONNECTION
```

The "bad" box had this entry:

```
2018-07-06 10:02:12.879 : nnftrne:Using tnsnames.ora address (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my.oracle.db.host)(PORT = 1521 for name ENV_CONNECTION
```

What this wound up translating to was one of the silliest and most surprising whitespace limitations I've ever encountered.

Remember that the wallet being used (along with its corresponding tnsnames.ora file) is used in Java as well.  My assumption was that both Python and Java would behave similarly when reading from this shared resource in that they would disregard newlines and whitespace where necessary.

I was clearly wrong.

The "good" box had entries that looked like this:

```
ENV_CONNECTION =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my.oracle.db.host)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = my_sid)
    )
  )
```

The "bad" boxes have entries that look like this:

```
ENV_CONNECTION =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my.oracle.db.host)(PORT = 1521
  ))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = my_sid)
    )
  )
```

The difference is subtle enough, but obvious to Python:  if the tnsnames.ora file is not properly formatted, cx_Oracle will *fail* to parse it, whereas Java is *fine* with this.

This feels like a bug on its own right, but fixing the formatting allows Python to connect again.

Comment: I'd like to follow up with the Oracle dev teams.  What platform are you on?  What JDBC version?  Did the files have *IX or Windows line termination?

Comment: @ChristopherJones:  I'll be able to confirm more at work at some point in the next 36 hours, but these files were built in RHEL boxes, so they were likely *nix line endings.  The JDBC version is between 7 and 8 if I recall correctly.

Comment: @ChristopherJones:  Able to confirm the above is all accurate.

Comment: I can't reproduce it with Python, even when using an older (11.2) Oracle client. Was there some non-printable character involved?